# How to pass a parameter in a xtrareport contained in a documentviewer

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a problem, when I try to charge a xtraReport in a documentviewer it doesn't refresh. I designed the report using a procedure from sql server with a parameter @IDA int, I did this:

```
XtraRptDoc report = new XtraRptDoc();
DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter paramFrom = new DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter();
paramFrom.Name = "@IDA";
paramFrom.Value = id;//value from a text box
report.CreateDocument();
report.Parameters.Add(paramFrom);
documentViewer1.DocumentSource = report;
```

My report starts with one parameter and it doesn't change. Thanks in advance.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Try using `report.CreateDocument(true)` or clear the dataset before using `CreateDocument()`. Probably [this issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q531843/how-to-refresh-report-displayed-in-the-documentviewer) is similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks. but how can I clear de dataset? I put this report.dataset.Clear(); however it doesn't exist. Please help me